# Time interrupt in C

Tags: c, time, timer, real-time, interrupt

with an ATmega328 I coded a time ago a LED-Matrix.
To achieve this, I used on the ATmega328 a timer interrupt (ISR), which was called every 10ms, so the Matrix didn't flickered.

Now I asked me, if operating systems (Windows, Linux, MacOSX) can do the same.
(I would expect it.)

Can somebody give me more infos, I don't find anything in the WWW.
I'd like to call a function every 1ms (just for learning).

Comment: *In general*, for general-purpose desktop/server operating systems, I'd say the answer is "no". On the other hand 1 kHz isn't super-often, but such systems are not designed to guarantee real-time response.

Answer (score 0):

There is two different ways to do it in kernel space or user space,
in kernel space I think you can do it on any OSes at least on Linux and Windows for sure.

From user space there is different real time extension of Linux and Windows,
for example https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page, without usage of this modifications I doubt that you can call some function with 1ms period from user space.

Comment: I'd like to run it in user space. So I should use CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT. Patching a linux-kernel shouldn't be the problem (I did it before). But what is with Windows?

Comment: before that you should patch kernel or use rt repo and then yes rebuild kernel with `CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I compiled now the latest kernel (Ubuntu Linux 15.04).

```
$ uname -a
Linux comments 4.1.10-rt11 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Thu Nov 5 14:29:16 CET 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Now I found this example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        struct timespec t;
        struct sched_param param;
        int interval = 50000; /* 50us*/

        /* Declare ourself as a real time task */

        param.sched_priority = MY_PRIORITY;
        if(sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, &param) == -1) {
                perror("sched_setscheduler failed");
                exit(-1);
        }

        /* Lock memory */

        if(mlockall(MCL_CURRENT|MCL_FUTURE) == -1) {
                perror("mlockall failed");
                exit(-2);
        }

        /* Pre-fault our stack */

        stack_prefault();

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC ,&t);
        /* start after one second */
        t.tv_sec++;

        while(1) {
                /* wait until next shot */
                clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &t, NULL);

                /* do the stuff */

                /* calculate next shot */
                t.tv_nsec += interval;

                while (t.tv_nsec >= NSEC_PER_SEC) {
                       t.tv_nsec -= NSEC_PER_SEC;
                        t.tv_sec++;
                }
   }
}
```

But I have more question, how can I determine the priority or how I can find out the priority from other running applications?

Does it works with threads too (libpthread)?